# Simple Password Encryption with Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is what I currently have but it is only printing the first Letter in the encryption. Where am I going wrong?

```
function crypto(){
var password = "Pizza2Day";
var flag = 0;
var encryptedPassword= "";
var originalValues = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
var encryptedValues = ["m", "h","t","f","g","k","b","p","j","w","e","r","q","s","l","n","i","u","o","x","z","y","v","d","c","a"];

for (var i=0; i < password.length; i++){
    flag=0;
    for (var r = 0; r < originalValues.length; r++){
        if (originalValues[r] == password.charAt(i)){
        encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword + encryptedValues[r];
        flag = 1;
        break;
        } else if (originalValues[r].toUpperCase() == password.charAt(i)) {
        encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword + 
encryptedValues[r].toUpperCase();
        flag = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
      encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword + password.charAt(i);
 }
  return encryptedPassword;
 }
   }
console.log("New Password: " + crypto());
```

Comment: please add the wanted result of the encryption.

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: Please tell my you are not using this to store your password in a database?

Comment: You `break` after a single swap

Comment: Please keep in mind that encryption done on the client side (for example JavaScript) is very prone to reverse engineering. It is really not save. If you're trying to encrypt password, use a server side encryption method, like bcrypt for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `return` statement outside the `for` loop:

```js
function crypto() {
  var password = "Pizza2Day";
  var flag = 0;
  var encryptedPassword = "";
  var originalValues = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  var encryptedValues = ["m", "h", "t", "f", "g", "k", "b", "p", "j", "w", "e", "r", "q", "s", "l", "n", "i", "u", "o", "x", "z", "y", "v", "d", "c", "a"];

  for (var i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
    flag = 0;
    for (var r = 0; r < originalValues.length; r++) {
      if (originalValues[r] == password.charAt(i)) {
        encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword + encryptedValues[r];
        flag = 1;
        break;
      } else if (originalValues[r].toUpperCase() == password.charAt(i)) {
        encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword +
          encryptedValues[r].toUpperCase();
        flag = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
      encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword + password.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  return encryptedPassword;
}
console.log("New Password: " + crypto());
```

Comment: When I run this through the console, crypto returns undefined.

Comment: @SockMonkey I can't reproduce any new issue. This snippet works for me in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could take another aproach by using strings instead of arrays for the characters and take [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) for getting the index of the given string.

A check if the index is `-1`, the value for a missing character in the string ins not necessary, because this value is taken as index for the the encrypted string. This returns either a character or `undefined`, which is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). In combination with a following [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()), the next value is taken, in this case the original character of the string to encode.

After a check if the original character is an upper case character, the character is converted to uppercase and then added to the result string.

```js
function crypto() {
    var password = "Pizza2Day",
        encryptedPassword = "",
        original =  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
        encrypted = "mhtfgkbpjwerqslniuoxzyvdca",
        i, character;

    for (i = 0; i < password.length; i++) {
        character = encrypted[original.indexOf(password[i].toLowerCase())] || password[i];
        if (password[i] === password[i].toUpperCase()) {
            character = character.toUpperCase();
        }
        encryptedPassword += character;
    }
    return encryptedPassword;
}

console.log("New Password: " + crypto());
```